# how to get response body in restify after event?

Tags: node.js, events, httpresponse, restify

I tried debugging/logging the response parameter in the function below but it doesn't contain the actual body.

function (request, response, route, error) {}

Above function was taken from restify documentation. Link below:
http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#Server-API

Here's my code:

```
server.on('after', function(req, resp, route, error) {
    console.log(resp);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code? Where is this function called? How? Just a heads up: the error parameter is usually the first.

Answer (score 1):

Read https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/blob/master/lib/response.js

On line 201, you can see that the real body sent is under resp._data